# Magento 2 Js want to call from my theme?

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options

I want to call the **complete** js files from `vendor` to `Smartwave/porto theme`.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-options.js
```

As per the customization i need complete two files.

My theme Name is: `Smartwave/porto`

I kept the above files in the below path:

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-box.js
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-options.js
```

did the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

but unable to get the changes.

Please suggest me thanks

Comment: First you have to do php bin/magento setup:upgrade then deploy,  that delete /pub/static/* files so make sure you have not directly changed in that   because your change removed .

Comment: Thanks for your reply Please confirm whether i am keeping the js files in the correct path ?

Answer (score 4):

copy from vendor to `Smartwave/porto` Theme

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-box.js
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js/price-options.js
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and check this locations

`pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/Magento_Catalog/js/price-box.js`
`pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_AU/Magento_Catalog/js/price-options.js`

your changes need to be here